# How to create mutliple select in custom Django admin form?

Tags: django, filter

I have a custom filter in django admin interface

```
class ClipExcludeRightsFilter(ListFilter):
  title = 'rights'
  parameter_name = 'exclude_rights'
  template = 'admin_mod/filters/exclude_rights.html'

  def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
    result = (
        ('avod', 'avod'),
        ('svod', 'svod'),
        ('est', 'est'),
        ('tvod', 'tvod')
    )
    return result

  def queryset(self, request, queryset):
      if self.value():
          urls_owner = ClipRestriction.objects.exclude(vod_system=self.value()).values_list('clip_id', flat=True)

          return queryset.filter(
              pk__in=urls_owner
          )
```

And in interface it returns list (select) and I can select just one attribute. But I need to implement multiple select. I found, that default template for this is **template/admin/filter.html**

```
{% load i18n %}
<h3>{% blocktrans with filter_title=title|capfirst %} By {{ filter_title }} {% endblocktrans %}</h3>
<select class="combobox">
    {% for choice in choices %}
        <option{% if choice.selected %} selected{% endif %} value="{{ choice.query_string|iriencode }}" >{{ choice.display }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Maybe I need to write my own template but no idea how to (I need to filter selected options instantly).

Comment: Only many to many relation support multiply choices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just selected all option:selected using jquery and then pass it as a parameter in my url.